# Passing Props to Child Component Which Uses Wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-wrapper

I am new to react.

In my app, I have a router component and I am using the render method to pass props. The child component has a wrapper used for authentication.

The problem is that when passing to to the component with the wrapper it has no visibility of the props. Sorry as I am new to this and don't know how to get the props down to to the child component in this situation.

I have created some test classes to illustrate the issue. Once the wrapper is added, I can't access the props, but it works without.

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import MyComponent from "./mycomponent";

class MyTest extends Component {
  // Then we add our constructor which receives our props
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // Next we establish our state
      this.state = {
          text: "Passing props to components"
      }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
      <div>
      <NavLink to="/rtest" replace>Route Test</NavLink>
      <Route path="/rtest" render={props => (<MyComponent {...props} text={this.state.text}/>)}/>
      </div>
      </HashRouter>
    )
  }

}

export default MyTest
```

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import AuthService from './auth/AuthService';
import withAuth from './auth/withAuth';

const Auth = new AuthService();


class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>HELLO</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(MyComponent);
```

WithAuth:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthService from './AuthService';

export default function withAuth(AuthComponent) {
    const Auth = new AuthService('http://localhost:8000');
    return class AuthWrapped extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                user: null
            }
        }

        componentWillMount() {
            //alert(this.props);
            if (!Auth.loggedIn()) {
                this.props.history.replace('/login')
            }
            else {
                try {
                    const profile = Auth.getProfile()
                    this.setState({
                        user: profile
                    })
                }
                catch(err){
                    Auth.logout()
                    this.props.history.replace('/login')
                }
            }
        }

        render() {
            if (this.state.user) {
                return (
                    <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user} />
                )
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What is withAuth? It clearly contributes to the problem. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for it.

Comment: withAuth is for authentication, I have included the code in the post.

Comment: Have you tried passing props to AuthComponent in withAuth HOC, and also to super of its constructor. 


`
render() {
            if (this.state.user) {
                return (
                    <AuthComponent history={this.props.history} user={this.state.user}  {...this.props}/>
                )
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        }
`

Comment: Many thanks, I think that is working. Please give me some time to fully test that in the actual app and I will let you know. I have some things I need to do at the moment before I can get back to it.

Comment: Thanks, that's working. If you want to type that as the answer then I will accept it as the answer.